# Zurb foundation 5, Bower, Compass, Sinatra configuration

Tags: sinatra, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm trying to add Zurb-foundation with sass into my sinatra app using the foundation-cli found [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html). I generated a foundation project and got all the files generated. I commented out the `config.rb` so I could configure Compass via the `app.rb` ie `mvp.rb`.

I'm having trouble linking to the actual assets found in the bower_components dir. I could link everything like so `get 'bower_components/file' do ... end` but I think you can use compass to automatically use the files based on the configuration. I'm not sure how to though.

In my haml views I have links to scripts that are not linked currently like `%script{ src: 'js/jquery.js' }`

config.rb

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
# http_path = "/"
# css_dir = "stylesheets"
# sass_dir = "scss"
# images_dir = "images"
# javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

app directory

```
Gemfile         config.rb       public
Gemfile.lock        index.html      stylesheets
js          views                   bower.json      
mvp.rb      bower_components
```

mvp.rb

```
  1#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                       
  2# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                   
  3require 'rubygems'
  4require 'bundler/setup'
  5require 'sinatra'
  6require 'haml'
  7require 'compass'
  8
  9configure do
 10  Compass.configuration do |config|
 11    config.project_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
 12    config.sass_dir = File.join '/views/scss'
 13    config.images_dir = 'views', 'images'
 14    config.http_path = '/'
 15    config.http_images_path = '/images'
 16    config.http_stylesheets_path = '/stylesheets'
 17    config.javascripts_dir = "js"
 18  end
 19
 20  set :haml, { format: :html5 }
 21  set :scss, { style: :compact, debug_info: false }
 22end
 23
 24get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do |path|
 25  content_type "text/css", charset: "utf-8"
 26  scss :"scss/#{params[:name]}", Compass.sass_engine_options
 27end
```